# Best way for a remote web app to authenticate users in my current web app?

Tags: authentication, web-applications, security, intranet

So a bit of background, I'm working on an existing web application which has a set of users, who are able to log in via a traditional login screen with a user name and password, etc.

Recently we've managed to score a client  (who have their own Intranet site), who are wanting to be able to have their users log into their Intranet site, and then have their users click a link on their Intranet which redirects to our application and logs them into it automatically.

I've had two suggestions on how to implement this so far:

1. Create a URL which takes 2 parameters (which are "username" and "password") and have the Intranet site pass those parameters to us (our connection is via SSL/TLS so it's all encrypted).  This would work fine, but it seems a little "hacky", and also means that the logins and passwords have to be the same on both systems (and having to write some kind of web service which can update the passwords for users - which also seems a bit insecure)
2. Provide a token to the Intranet, so when the client clicks on a link on the Intranet, it sends the token to us, along with the user name (and no password) which means they're authenticated.  Again, this sounds a bit hacky as isn't that essentially the same as providing everyone with the same password to log in?

So to summarise, I'm after the following things:

1. A way for the users who are already authenticated on the Intranet to log into our system without too much messing around, and without using an external system to authenticate, i.e. LDAP / Kerberos
2. Something which isn't too specific to this client, and can easily be implemented by other Intranets to log in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but I hate even more a question with no answer.  In the end we went with a very similar implementation of SalesForce's delegated authentication SSO implementation.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/How_to_Implement_Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com

Essentially the solution has a trusted site, known as the delegated authentication authority, who has a list of users who are logged into the company intranet.

When the user logs into the company intranet, and they click a link to our application, the company intranet will pass the user name and a generated token (which expires after a set amount of time) to our application.

Our application will then check if the user name is on our site, and if so, send the username / token (along with the source IP and a few other parameters) to the delegated authentication authority.  If all those items match on the delegated authentication authority, it returns true and the user can log in.  If it returns false the user is denied access.

We've found this system to work quite well, and even implemented a couple of extra security features like SSL, client side certificates, VPN tunnel, and even restricting the IP addresses which can access the site and the delegated authentication authority.

I know it's bad form to answer your own question but I hope this helps someone else who might be having the same problem ...

Answer (score 2):

Both of your suggested options are insecure, even if you use SSL. Never pass credentials on a URL, put them in the HTTP request by using POST.

There is a standard called [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) and this can be used to solve your problem. The challenge is choosing which version to implement. I would choose [SAML 2.0](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/13525/sstc-saml-exec-overview-2.0-cd-01-2col.pdf).

Google Apps [implements](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/saml_reference_implementation.html) a flavor of SAML 2.0 and allow you to authenticate using your intranet credentials. In the case of your application, you would be the service provider and your client would be the identity provider. As long as you implement the standard correctly you should be able to support any new client (identity provider). Here is a [list](http://saml.xml.org/wiki/saml-open-source-implementations) of SAML implementations you might want to take a look at. If you need the client to pass over information in addition to the authentication information then SAML can facilitate this with metadata.

You will still need to implement SSL to encrypt network traffic.